# How do I generate LinkButton's that are created from another Link_Command event on Postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

Ok so I have a list of LinkButton's that upon being clicked are creating more LinkButton's inside of a table to do postback. For example, Each user has a list of activities or jobs. So when that user is clicked it creates a list of their jobs in a table. These jobs then need to do postback to get their respected content.

**C# Code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        lstUsers = GetUsers();
        AddLinkButton("all", "All", tabList, link_Command);
        foreach (var item in lstUsers) {
            AddLinkButton(item.UID.ToString(), item.Name, tabList, link_Command);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { 

    }
}

void link_Clicked(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
    List<Job> jList = GetJobs(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    foreach (Job job in jList) {
        HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
        AddCell(job.JobID.ToString(), job.Name, row);
        jobsTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
} 


void AddCell(string id, string text, HtmlTableRow row) {
    HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
    LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
    link.ID = id;
    link.Text = text;
    link.Command += new CommandEventHandler(job_Command);
    link.CommandArgument = id;
    link.Style.Add("color", "black");
    cell.Controls.Add(link);
    row.Cells.Add(cell);
}

void AddLinkButton(string id, string text, HtmlGenericControl list, CommandEventHandler handler) {
        LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
        link.ID = id;
        link.Text = text;
        link.Command += new CommandEventHandler(handler);
        link.CommandArgument = id;
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Controls.Add(link);
        list.Controls.Add(li);
    }
```

Above in the Page_Load event I am creating the list of users. When a user is clicked it is firing link_Clicked. link_Clicked then creates a list of rows pertaining to that User, so activity or job links.

My problem is that I need to determine in Page_Load whether or not one of the links created in link_Clicked was actually clicked. If anyone has better suggestions to the way that I am doing this I am definitely all ears. I am very new to asp.net development so there is probably a better route to go for this.

Comment: Check if it's postback on the Page_Load [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx). It's not an answer to your question but seems like you're missing that.

Comment: @Daniel yeah IsPostBack won't really help me since I am doing multiple postbacks to the same page. I need to be able to differentiate between which postback it was.

Comment: Yes, the thing is that it will always launch `Page_Load`, that's why in general, you might want to check `IsPostBack` property [see lifecycle stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). If you check that, your `Page_Load` code won't run when your `link_Clicked` event is fired and that way you can take control. Otherwise, you can use something like `Attributes` property to flag your link buttons on each case, and then check this property again to know which link was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
string test1234 = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
```

That passes me back the ID of the control which is exactly what I needed.

I found a tutorial [here](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write you own custom method to track the event

A very nice example given here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/82086/How-to-know-which-control-has-raised-a-postback